# What could be the best approach to pass data in nested child components, in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a scenario, where for example

```html
<parent-comp>
 <side-bar></side-bar>
 <item-details></item-details>
</parent-comp>

<side-bar>
 <item-list></item-list>
</side-bar>
```

I need to share items list into the components 'ItemListComponent' and 'ItemDetailsComponent', keeping the hierarchy in mind

**Approach 1**

I can fetch the items from ItemService in ParentComponent and send it via attribute/property
`<sidebar [pages]="pages"></sidebar>` >>>  `<item-list [pages]="pages"></item-list>` and `<item-details[pages]="pages"></item-details>`

I need to pass data through SidebarComponent to transfer it to ItemListComponent.

**Approach 2**

Fetching items from ItemService in the ParentComponent and instead of passing via attribute/property it emits the data (RxJs) let say with event name 'ItemDataFetched', and ItemList/ItemDetails component subscribed to that event.

What will be the best approach among the two? or is there any other better approach?

Answer (score 3):

Check here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction the ways proposed by the angular team.

I'd say input binding is the way to go in most cases.

1. It is the standard way of patent child communication. It will be what's expected by future developers to see, making debugging easier.
2. Event passing data is to be avoided in general. If you are not using event binding with emitter for child to parent communication, you are out of the angular cycle and can cause unexpected problems.
3. Using a service is always an option. Bear in mind though that services are singletons. Thus have their own limitations.

By the way, I would expect the child component to inform the parent of the selection and pass only the selected item's  page to the item-details component. Not the entire collection.

Comment: on the last two lines, in that case I have to inform the parent-comp via EventEmitter? Or I can have service having impl. Observable and share the data and parent/child subscribed to it? by an event, I mean that!

Comment: You can use both, but it's better to go with event emitter. That's the way all official angular components are made, and that's how we should do it roo.

Comment: hmm, Angular does propose how parent/child components work, but what about having a single point of interaction let say DataStoreService? All the components subscribed to respective observables, the question here when/which comp. will initiate/emit on that subject?

Comment: If you need to share state between many active non parent-child components then you should check some solution kind redux. The idea is to get the data in the composition component. If you need not manipulate data and get them from a store, then it does make sense to use a service. I'm mentioning redux as it alleviates some of the singleton service problems.